# how to convert list to np.array in numba?

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy-ndarray, numba

```
@njit
def func():
     a = np.array([1.2, 5.3])
     tmp = nb.typed.List()
    tmp.append(a)
    return np.array(tmp)
```

I want to convert a python list or numba.typed.List to np.array, but I can't do it.
How can I realize this function. The picture below show the error.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uop3L.png

Answer (score 0):

How about just returning the numpy array directly instead of this?

```
@njit
def func():
  return np.array([1.2, 5.3])
```

Maybe I'm missing something?